# Bootstrap4 radio button background and fill color

Tags: bootstrap-4

I was wondering how can I change Bootstraps radio button background color and fill color?

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1"> radio label
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a browser default. Notoriously difficult/impossible to style. You should hide it instead and then use custom elements to fake it. That way you can get any appearance you want.

Comment: Thanks WebDevBooster. How can we do that?

Comment: Any luck in changing fill color ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `custom-radio` class like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Toggle this custom radio</label>
</div>
```

That gives you the flexibility to style the radio input in any way you want.

The background color (i.e. what you see in the default, unchecked state) is controlled by this rule:

```html
.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
```

I changed it from the default grey to orange there.

And here are the css rules to control all states:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
/* This is the default state */
.custom-radio .custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: darkorange;  /* orange */
}

/* This is the checked state */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-color: greenyellow;  /* green */
    /* this bg image SVG is just a white circle, you can replace it with any valid SVG code */
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3E%3Ccircle r='3' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E); 
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* active state i.e. displayed while the mouse is being pressed down */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:active ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000; /* red */
}
    
/* the shadow; displayed while the element is in focus */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 123, 255, 0.25); /* pink, 25% opacity */
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Toggle this custom radio</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, but how abut styles? What are names of the classes?

Comment: CSS for background & fill doesn't seem to work? Maybe class missing?

Comment: Sweet thanks. Don't understand one thing tho. Why custom radio shows as square in my code? Any idea?

Comment: because you haven't copied `border-radius: 50%;` from my code.

Comment: I did but had to add !important to it.

Comment: One more thing I noticed that on click background turns into red. How can we fix that? Many thanks!

Comment: Of course. Just read my comments in that code snippet above and look for the color next to `/* red */`. That's the part you need to change. All other parts have comments attached to them as well, describing what they are for.

Comment: The original Bootstrap color was blue for everything but I gave each part a different color on purpose so that you can tell them apart more easily.

Comment: You did fantastic job very impressed!

Answer (score 6):

See the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #7B1FA2;
  background-color: #7B1FA2;
}
</style>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">Toggle this custom radio</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">Or toggle this other custom radio</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @ayaio you just remove one single char `#` in your edit. What is the point? Unbelievable.

Comment: @ayaio I disagree with you completely. But whatever. You are the boss.

Comment: Use `box-shadow: none !important;` if you don't want blue shadow around the radio button.