# How to check Bootstrap 4's custom checkbox state?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In their documentation here : http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1

It's never mentioned how to properly use the custom checkboxes, using the inspector it doesn't seem like any class is added, and the value is always "on".

It's also not mentioned how do I change their state via html or javascript.

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2n40w13k/1/

Js :

```
$('.custom-control-input').on('change', evt => {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
})
```

Comment: $(evt.target).prop('checked') ?

Comment: "on" is the default value for checkboxes. you have to add a value to `<input type="checkbox" value="whateveryouwant">` if you want to change this. this is vanilla oldschool HTML.

Comment: @ZimSystem You pointed him back to the link in his first paragraph...

Comment: I just thought it was confusing the phrase "We use the sibling selector to properly style our custom form indicator"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2n40w13k/8/

Comment: Functionally it's the same as any checkbox.. it's just styled differently using CSS pseudo selectors.

Comment: @Mojimi The reason that phrase is confusing is because the custom checkbox is NOT using the HTML input element at all. That element is *hidden* via css. So, what you are seeing only looks like a checkbox but it's not the actual HTML input for the checkbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in your event handler:

```
$(evt.target).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 2):

That is done by using the `:checked`, `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes.

So, when you click a custom checkbox (or radio button), the `:checked` pseudo-class is applied to it. When you click it again, that pseudo-class is removed. And that's what you target with css to change appearance.

The same is true for JavaScript/jQuery. You'd need to add/remove the corresponding pseudo-class (`:checked`) via JavaScript/jQuery if you wanted to control it that way.

The **last** snippet of my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401949/8270343

explains it in further detail.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply your answer to javascript/jquery

Comment: You'd need to add the corresponding pseudo-class via JavaScript/jQuery if you wanted to control it that way.

Comment: just in case, angular 2+ example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214655/angular-2-checkbox-two-way-data-binding