# Is it possible to trigger onChange when Bootstrap 4's custom checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I've built one of Bootstrap 4's custom checkboxes which looks like this:

```
<div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input onChange={ (evt) => { console.log("CHANGED") }}
        type="checkbox" 
        className="custom-control-input" 
        id="barChartsCheckbox" />
    <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="barChartsCheckbox">Bar Charts</label>
</div>
```

I'm using React, so I want to detect a change in state to re-render the page, but **the `onChange` event is not triggered**.

As far as I understand, Bootstrap's custom checkboxes work by applying a `:checked` pseudoclass, so is it possible to catch that change via an `onChange` function?

**EDIT**

It seems that applying an onChange listener via jQuery works, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914928/how-to-check-bootstrap-4s-custom-checkbox-state) question

```
$('.custom-control-input').on('change', evt => {
    console.log("test");
})
```

So why doesn't the `onChange` attribute work in React?

Comment: It's working for me https://codesandbox.io/s/ojxz1w1rzy

Comment: Okay, it's probably some custom Javascript from the template I bought interfering with things.