# Bootstrap 5 Radio Button change Background Color in NET Core

Tags: css, razor-pages, bootstrap-5, asp.net-core-5.0

Since moving to Bootstrap 5, I'm no longer able to change the background color with a CSS modification.

Any have any ideas to fix this?

Razor code sample:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="margin-top: 1.5em">
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div>
        Conditional Logic:
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check form-check-inline ms-2">
        <input checked class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioBtn1" id="customRadio1" value="OR">
        <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="customRadio1">OR</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioBtn2" id="customRadio2" value="AND">
        <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="customRadio2">AND</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS no longer works:

```
/* Custom Radio Button color before checked */
.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #6C757D;
}
```

The result I want is to change the white background nearer to the theme's background color:

[image]

Comment: the .custom-control-label class is not applied in your html

Comment: small typo, have updated code sample but still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a bootstrap issue as trying the same without bootstrap also would not work. Is there a reason you are using the ::before selector? If you remove this you should get the desired result.

Comment: I was going by a thread for Bootsrap 4 which had 33qty votes as the correct answer, so one would assume this was the solution for Bootsratp 4 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401587/bootstrap4-radio-button-background-and-fill-color

Comment: Possible that there is some need for the selector in bootstrap 4. However, in Bootstrap 5 you should not need this and removing it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, think it's sorted now... Removed the ::before but then found it was the label that was changing, so I swapped the CSS pointer to the input, not the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the CSS was slightly wrong, this below seems to work OK:

```
.custom-control-input {
    background-color: #6C757D;
}
```

Updated Razor/HMTL:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="margin-top: 1.5em">
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div>
        Conditional Logic:
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline ms-2">
        <input checked class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioBtn1" id="customRadio1" value="OR">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="customRadio1">OR</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioBtn1" id="customRadio2" value="AND">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="customRadio1">AND</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]